# Angular: How I can pass a value to child component after successful output eventemitter

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter, angular-output

How I can setvalue to true in angular after successful emit operation. How I can pass a flag to **app.child.ts** after successful api call in parent component?

**app.parent.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm">
  <input matInput
         formControlName="amount"
         type="number"/>
  <button *ngIf="hasValue"
         (click)="onItemRemoved(element, index)">
         Remove
  </button>
</from>
```

**app.parent.ts**

```
@Output() remove: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    
onItemRemoved(value, index) {
   this.remove.emit({ value, index });
}
```

**app.child.html**

```
<app-parent (remove)="remove($event)" </app-parent>
```

**app.child.ts**

```
remove(event) {
  console.log('item removing with api call...');
}
```

Comment: the child component hold the parent component selector?? something is not clear in the scenario..

Comment: Can you explain more the scenario? so after emitting an event from the child to parent, you want a return from parent to child?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. @RebaiAhmed yes. I want a return from parent component so i can hide button in child component